# Pythonic way to efficiently handle variable number of return args

Tags: python, coding-style, return-value, calling-convention

So I have a function that can either work quietly or verbosely.  In quiet mode it produces an output.  In verbose mode it also saves intermediate calculations to a list, though doing so takes extra computation in itself.

Before you ask, yes, this is an identified bottleneck for optimization, and the verbose output is rarely needed so that's fine.

So the question is, what's the most pythonic way to efficiently handle a function which may or may not return a second value?  I suspect a pythonic way would be named tuples or dictionary output, e.g.

```
def f(x,verbose=False):
    result = 0
    verbosity = []
    for _ in x:
        foo = # something quick to calculate
        result += foo
        if verbose:
            verbosity += # something slow to calculate based on foo
    return {"result":result, "verbosity":verbosity}
```

But that requires constructing a dict when it's not needed.

Some alternatives are:

```
# "verbose" changes syntax of return value, yuck!
return result if verbose else (result,verbosity)
```

or using a mutable argument

```
def f(x,verbosity=None):
    if verbosity:
        assert verbosity==[[]]
    result = 0
    for _ in x:
        foo = # something quick to calculate
        result += foo
        if verbosity:
            # hard coded value, yuck
            verbosity[0] += # something slow to calculate based on foo
    return result

# for verbose results call as
verbosity = [[]]
f(x,verbosity)
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Which version(s) of Python? If 3.x you could *always* return a list/tuple, and use `result, *other_stuff = f(x, verbosity)`. See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1893304/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/14147675/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10223427/3001761, ...

Comment: 2.7 but thanks for educating me on the (my!) future

Comment: ...although I don't like the feel of that either, as non-verbose calls to f have to know about discarding other stuff.  The mutable default argument avoids that issue.

Comment: The dictionary doesn't just provide a container for the two values; it provides a *consistent* interface for the caller of `f`, who doesn't have to know the value of the `verbosity` argument to use the return value. In other words, the existence (and not any particular value) of the `verbosity` argument makes the `dict` necessary.

Comment: The mutable argument version would be neater if you test by *identity*, `is not None`, then you can just pass `[]` instead of `[[]]`.

Comment: You can return a lazily-evaluated function that only performs the additional calculation if it's accessed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my original solution did that, but some versions of this function require direct assignment to verbosity which would fail to mutate the argument if not wrapped in another []

Comment: Multiprocessing.Process uses the convention of tuples which enables consistent function interfaces through *args syntax.  However https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists and the corresponding python2 document says this is the least frequently used option and gives preference to keyword arguments which also promotes consistent interfaces through **kwargs syntax.  Based on that I suggest using the latter unless its inconvenient and in that case use the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return `verbosity`.  Make it an optional function argument, passed in by the caller, mutated in the function if not empty.

The non-pythonic part of some answers is the need to test the structure of the return value.  Passing mutable arguments for optional processing avoids this ugliness.

Comment: Ultimately I think this makes most sense, so I'll accept it.  I'm not convinced you have to test return value structure though, as I had imagined the verbose argument to hold a constant at compile time anyway, though I guess somebody could have a call that changes at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I like the first option, but instead of passing a `verbose` parameter in the function call, return a tuple of a quick result and a lazily-evaluated function:

```
import time

def getResult(x):
    quickResult = x * 2

    def verboseResult():
        time.sleep(5)
        return quickResult * 2

    return (quickResult, verboseResult)

# Returns immediately
(quickResult, verboseResult) = getResult(2)

print(quickResult)     # Prints immediately
print(verboseResult()) # Prints after running the long-running function
```

Comment: I haven't benchmarked this but won't the function definition for `verboseResult()` take significant time?  Or if it doesn't then the binding of `quickResult` to its outer context will?  Aside from that I agree this looks nicely pythonic.

Comment: Also alas I don't see this working in my original example because `verbosity` needs access to a range of valued throughout the `for` loop.  If we're saving these on the off chance `verboseResult()` gets called later then we're wasting time and memory (genuinely quite a lot in my case).